# Slowly change dimension

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Using slowly change dimension type 2, when a new line with the same source primary key is added into my dimension table, a new surrogate key is created, OK, but how is it mirrored within my fact table?

How will my fact table know that a new SK will have to be created to refer to that SK in my dimension table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The mapping of the natural key to the SK of the dimension is done **while populating the fact table**. Each new record that contains the natural
dimension key is mapped using the dimension table and the (selected) transaction timestamp to get the corresponding SK, which is stored in the fact table.

This procedure works fine if *the weather is nice*, but there are few caveats:

If the dimension may be subject of *late arriving changes* (i.e. you get change that was valid in last month), you end with fact table that maps to a dimension record that is obsolete after the change.

In extreme cases you may need to load fact table records with a dimension key that have no entries in the dimension table at all.

You must consider those cases and check the relevance upon your data.

One possible approach is to (additonally) store the natural dimension key in the fact table and to delay the mapping to the dimension table in to the reporting queries. (i.e. you use alwys the last valid dimension table at the reporting time).
One additional advantage of this approach is that you may use several different timestamps from the fact table (e.g. transaction date or bookung date).

Comment: Better explained than my answer, I'm deleting mine